# What is the best method to show selected filters from very long lists?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, ios, selection, lists

I need to find a solution for displaying flagged items from a very long list.

The following pics shows the filter panel of the iPad App. 
Users can select all the items or search for specific items in the list. If they want to select that filter they need to flag it.

My problem is that this list can be very long (more than possible 100 items) and items flagged can be many scroll away and therefore not visible to users.

How can I give a proper feedback of items already flagged?

Thank you!

[image: filter panel with full list]
[image: filter panel - item checked]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Include a selector** at the top which allows users to choose between "show all options" and "show flagged options".  It may be clear enough to just call them "All" and "Flagged", but you would neet to test this.

Comment: Yes this is a solution a was thinking about. I just do not want to complicate the UI too much... end users of this app are not very skilled.